# Browser back button using Nextjs refresh the component after a few seconds

Tags: reactjs, next.js, back

I'm using React and Next.js in this project, I have a list of products that I get from a query in one batch and display 15 at a time. I manage this using the parameter `p`, for pages. So every time I load another page, param `p` changes its number.

The problem is that when the user clicks on browser back button, the products change (as they should), but after a few seconds I get a full refresh of the page.

Here is how I do the params change:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof window != "undefined" && router.isReady) {
    router.push(
      {
        pathName: window.location.pathname,
        query: { ...router.query, p: page }
      },
      null,
      { shallow: true });
  }
}, [page]);
```

I tried `router.beforePopState` but I can't prevent page from refreshing. I also tried:

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

Which helps since it doesn't reload the page (it doesn't make any change, but I can solve this problem), the issue here is the browser shows two alerts...

I need one of two things:

- The page doesn't refresh and the products are correctly shown (as it happens now, but then it reload the page)
- Or the page does the reload, but without showing the change of products before the reload.